# Are all the subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ closed or open (or neither) in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

At each integer $n$, $B_r(n)=\{n\}$ for small $r$, so $B_r(n)=\{n\} \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Since any subset is a union of some integers, does this imply that all subsets are open?

Also, since there is no limit point in a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ because there's no sequence of integers converging to an integer, does this mean all the subsets contains all the limit points (which is 0)?

If yes, does this mean any subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is both closed and open?

Comment: Yes: every subset of $\Bbb Z$ is indeed *clopen* (i.e., both closed and open).

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb Z$ has the discrete topology, which means that all sets are both open and closed.